# angular2 ngx-treeview Issue arrorw doesnt apear in the tree

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 project, And i am implementing ngx-treeview, 
my problem is that after implementing ngx-treeview, the arrows for expansion doesn't appear.
Any help?

Comment: did you add "Font Awesome 4"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Font Awesome 4 to get that arrows css.

you need to install it first:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

Then add it in **angular-cli.json**

```
"apps": [
          {
             "root": "src",
             "outDir": "dist",
             ....
             "styles": [
                "styles.css",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
             ],
             ...
         }
       ]
],
```

Dont forget to run **ng build** before **ng serve**